# MS SQL DB server 2019: Async Mirroring(High-Performance) is Available in standard edition(2019)?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019, mirroring

MS SQL DB server 2019: Async Mirroring(High-Performance) is available only in the enterprise edition(2019). or also Available in standard edition(2019)?.

Answer (score 1):

Database Mirroring is an available feature in SQL Server 2019 as per the article [Editions and supported features of SQL Server 2019](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/editions-and-components-of-sql-server-2019?view=sql-server-ver16) (Microsoft Learn).

```
+--------------------+------------+----------+-------+--------------------------------+---------+
|      Feature       | Enterprise | Standard |  Web  | Express with Advanced Services | Express |
+--------------------+------------+----------+-------+--------------------------------+---------+
| ...                | ...        | ...      | ...   | ...                            | ...     |
| Database mirroring | Yes        | Yes 2    | Yes 3 | Yes 3                          | Yes 3   |
| ...                | ...        | ...      | ...   | ...                            | ...     |
+--------------------+------------+----------+-------+--------------------------------+---------+
```

However, there is a foot note (2) that states:

> <sup>2</sup> Full safety only

If you look in the documentation [Setting Up Database Mirroring (SQL Server)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/database-mirroring/setting-up-database-mirroring-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16) (Microsoft Learn), then the information for **Full safety only** states:

> By default a session is set to **full transaction safety** (SAFETY is set to FULL), which starts the **session in synchronous**, high-safety mode without automatic failover. You can reconfigure the session to run in high-safety mode with automatic failover or in asynchronous, high-performance mode, as follows:
>
> - High-safety mode with automatic failover
>   If you want a high-safety mode session to support automatic failover, add a witness server instance.
>   To add a witness
>
>   - Add a Database Mirroring Witness Using Windows Authentication (Transact-SQL)
>   - Establish a Database Mirroring Session Using Windows Authentication (SQL Server Management Studio)

So taking the **foot note** from the features and editions table and the details for **High Safety mode** one can conclude that:

**High Performance mode**, which corresponds to **asynchronous mode** is **not available in the Standard Edition**.

---

Please take note that Database Mirroring is a deprecated feature and shouldn't be used:

> **Note:**
> This feature will be removed in a future version of Microsoft SQL Server. Avoid using this feature in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use this feature. Use Always On availability groups instead.

Comment: Thanks for the valuable information...

Answer (score 0):

You can use Availability Groups in SQL Server 2019, however it is limited to 1 database per AG and you are not able to have a readable secondary.

See the following links for information
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/basic-availability-groups-always-on-availability-groups?view=sql-server-ver16

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/editions-and-components-of-sql-server-2019?view=sql-server-ver16